# error in saving the username at the launch of application in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to do the following thing

At the start of the app, first thing it should do is ask user to enter name and then through a welcome screen with that name.

Then When the app is used next time it should just give welcome screen (should not ask for name again)

I have created the code for the above.
I have used shared preference saved

My code is

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
       }

       private void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
        String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");
        textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
        textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
       }
    }
```

But how to check whetehr user is already registered?

Thanks
Tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to use `SharedPrefernces`.. use this::

first declare it...

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PrefernceNAme";
public static final String PREFS_ITEM = "PrefItemStored";
```

to get values from it, use:::

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);    
mode = preferences.getString(PREFS_ITEM, "PrefItemStored");
```

and to add values in `SharedPrefernces`, use::

```
getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(PREFS_ITEM, value)
                .commit();
```

Comment: I have used this way and it worked fine, easy to remember. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> But how to check whetehr user is already registered?

When user starts application first time that time you will check if any preference value exists for name key.

Following snippet will help you

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);


String namePrefrence = sharedPreferences.getString("uname", "");

if (namePrefrence.length() == 0) {  

    //User not registered!!  
    Show dialog where user will enter username

} else {

    //User is registered!!  
    just show welcome screen

}
```